# mysql php multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have this mysql result:

```
pic  userid   username
 A     1       peter
 A     2       jack
 B     3       maria
 B     4       anna
```

I want an multidimensional array like this:

```
{"pics": 
   {"pic" => "A", "users" => [
                     {"userid" => "1", "username" => "peter"}, 
                     {"userid" => "2", "username" = "jack"}
                   ],
    "pic" => "B", "users" => [
                     {"userid" => "3", "username" => "maria"}, 
                     {"userid" => "4", "username" = "anna"}
                   ]}
```

Thank you!

I've tried this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT A.pic, B.userid, B.username FROM `tabpics` A LEFT JOIN tabuser B ON (A.userid = B.userid)");
while ($date=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$pics[$date['pic']][] = array("userid"=>$date['userid'],"username"=>$date['username']);
}
```

and this is the result:

```
{"A"=> {"userid" => "1", "username" => "peter"}, "A" => {"userid" => "2", "username" = "jack"} ....
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: so show us what you tried before, what is sql and php you have, then what is the problem you faced

Comment: Simply Sitting In Home. Question Came To Mind. Posted Here. What's Wrong Man. Post Your Code Here.

Comment: Sorry.. I've edited my posting

Comment: So whats wrong. Your result is the same as what you want?

Comment: no, it isn't the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
$userArr = "";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT A.pic, B.userid, B.username FROM `tabpics` A LEFT JOIN tabuser B ON (A.userid = B.userid)"); 
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $userArr[$data['pic']][] = array("userid"=>$data['userid'],"username"=>$data['username']); 
}

if(count($userArr) > 0){
    foreach ($userArr as $picName => $valArr) {
        $pics[]=array("pic" => $picName ,"users" => $valArr);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($pics);
```